# NEDB Query returning false positives with $nin on array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, nedb

I'm having an issue using the NEDB `find()` query structure.

The `find()` query below should return all new messages: sent to the `email` or the `All` group specified and that have not been read or sent by the `email` specified.

However, it is returning false positives. For example, the two items in the flat file (below) are returned in the results, despite the fact that the `email` **IS** in the array of the property being evaluated. I am using the `$nin` operator and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong? All suggestions welcomed :)

```
var email = 'anotheraddress@gmail.com';
var message_query = [];
    message_query.push({$and: [{to: 'All'}, {'data.readBy': {$nin: [email]}}]});
    message_query.push({$and: [{to: email}, {'data.read': {$exists: false}}]});

    message
        .find({
            $and: [
                {$not: {from: email}},
                {$or: message_query}
            ]
        })
        .exec(function (err, results) {

        });
```

Here's a snippet of what the flat file looks like. These two should not be returned, but they are :/

```
...

{ 
  to: 'All',
  toname: 'Some Name',
  from: 'someaddress@gmail.com',
  fromname: 'Some other Name',
  message: 'A message for all...',
  timestamp: 1502473320,
  imtype: 'msg',
  _id: 'K66iP3dZHbYTfGgK',
  data:
   { readBy:
      [ 'someotheraddress@gmail.com',
        'anotheraddress@gmail.com' ] } 
},
{ 
  to: 'All',
  toname: 'Some Name',
  from: 'someoneelse@gmail.com',
  fromname: 'Some other Name',
  message: 'A message for all...',
  timestamp: 1502473420,
  imtype: 'msg',
  _id: 'K66iP3dZNyNxfGgK',
  data:
   { readBy:
      [ 'someotheraddress@gmail.com',
        'anotheraddress@gmail.com' ] } 
}

...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `$nin` operator - it does not work as it does in mongo.

NEDB's `$in` operator works differently: Only one of the operands can be an array. Check out the definition of [`$in`](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/blob/397c6821ca4e011aa4f8483e0ded3d24c882d9f8/lib/model.js#L601) ([`$nin`](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/blob/397c6821ca4e011aa4f8483e0ded3d24c882d9f8/lib/model.js#L613) is just a negation of `$in` after all). When it checks if [things are equal](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/blob/397c6821ca4e011aa4f8483e0ded3d24c882d9f8/lib/model.js#L540) for arrays, it makes sure only one of the items is an array i.e. neither `a` or `b[i]` can  be arrays. If they are, then return false. `$nin` hence returns true - explaining the presence of both the documents in the results.

You can verify this as follows: try changing `[email]` to something like `["someotheraddress@gmail.com", "anotheraddress@gmail.com", "foo@bar.com"]`, you'll notice that the two results disappear - proving that it doesn't check if each element in `data.readBy` is not in the list we provide, but check if the entire `data.readBy` is present in the list we provide.

**Solution**
Use `{ $not: { elemMatch }`

You can overcome the problem by changing your query to the following:

```
message_query.push({
  $and: [{ to: "All" }, { $not: { "data.readBy": { $elemMatch: email } } }]
});
```

Here's the code to verify:

```
const Datastore = require("nedb");

const db = new Datastore({
  inMemoryOnly: true,
  autoload: false
});

db.insert(
  [
    {
      to: "All",
      toname: "Some Name",
      from: "someaddress@gmail.com",
      fromname: "Some other Name",
      message: "A message for all...",
      timestamp: 1502473320,
      imtype: "msg",
      data: {
        readBy: ["someotheraddress@gmail.com", "anotheraddress@gmail.com"]
      }
    },
    {
      to: "All",
      toname: "Some Name",
      from: "someoneelse@gmail.com",
      fromname: "Some other Name",
      message: "A message for all...",
      timestamp: 1502473420,
      imtype: "msg",
      data: {
        readBy: ["someotheraddress@gmail.com", "anotheraddress@gmail.com"]
      }
    },
    {
      to: "All",
      toname: "Some Name",
      from: "someoneelse@gmail.com",
      fromname: "Some other Name",
      message: "A message for all...",
      timestamp: 1502473420,
      imtype: "msg",
      data: {
        readBy: ["someotheraddress@gmail.com" ]
      }
    },
    {
      to: "foo@bar.com",
      toname: "Some Name",
      from: "someoneelse@gmail.com",
      fromname: "Some other Name",
      message: "A message for all...",
      timestamp: 1502473420,
      imtype: "msg",
      data: {
        readBy: ["someotheraddress@gmail.com", "anotheraddress@gmail.com"]
      }
    },
    {
      to: "anotheraddress@gmail.com",
      toname: "Some Name",
      from: "someoneelse@gmail.com",
      fromname: "Some other Name",
      message: "A message for all...",
      timestamp: 1502473420,
      imtype: "msg",
      data: {
        read: true
      }
    },
    {
      to: "anotheraddress@gmail.com",
      toname: "Some Name",
      from: "someoneelse@gmail.com",
      fromname: "Some other Name",
      message: "A message for all...",
      timestamp: 1502473420,
      imtype: "msg",
      data: {
      }
    }
  ],
  (...args) => {
    var email = "anotheraddress@gmail.com";

    var _list = ["someotheraddress@gmail.com", "anotheraddress@gmail.com", "foo@bar.com"];

    var message_query = [];

    message_query.push({
      $and: [{ to: "All" }, { $not: { "data.readBy": { $elemMatch: email } } }]
    });

    // message_query.push({
    //   $and: [{ to: "All" }, { "data.readBy": { $nin: [email] } }]
    // });

    // message_query.push({
    //   $and: [{ to: "All" }, { "data.readBy": { $nin: _list } }]
    // });

    message_query.push({
      $and: [{ to: email }, { "data.read": { $exists: false } }]
    });

    db.find({
      $and: [ { $not: { from: email } }, { $or: message_query } ]
    }).exec(function(err, results) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
    });

  }
);
```

Comment: Good morning Manas! Thank you for the detailed response. Will try and confirm your answer now.

Comment: Good day to you too, Adam. Sure :)

Comment: Your answer is indeed spot on! Thanks for taking the time to look into this. Have marked as correct but cannot issue bounty for another 12 hours!

Comment: Glad I could help :)